# Complement of closed convex set in Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $H$ be a real Hilbert space and $C$ be a closed convex subset of $H$.

Is it true that if $x$ is a boundary point of $C$ then there exists $y\in H\setminus C$ such that the set $\{x+t(y-x);\;t>0\}$ lies in $H\setminus C$ ?

Thank you for any hint.

Answer (score 2):

We prove this fact by contradiction. The negation of your assertion is: For every $y \in H \setminus C$, there is $t > 0$, such that $x + t \, (y - x) \in C$. It is also clear that this property holds for all $y \in C$ (choose $t = 1$).

Hence, for all $d \in H$, there is $t > 0$ with $x + t d \in C$.
This means that the point $x$ belongs to the core (or: algebraic interior) of $C$. For closed, convex sets in Hilbert spaces, we have that the core coincides with the interior. Hence, $x$ belongs to the interior. This is a contradiction since $x$ is assumed to be a boundary point.

Comment: Could you give a proof, or reference, for the statement "core = interior"?

Comment: This is a corollary of Baire's theorem. I think it can be found in books on convex analysis in infinite dimensions. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_interior#Relation_to_interior.

Comment: Very interesting.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I will use the following fact: if $x\in C$ and $x_0 \in \operatorname{int} C$ then $\lambda x + (1-\lambda)x_0 \in \operatorname{int} C$ for all $\lambda\in (0,1)$.

If $C$ has interior points, then the following construction works: Let $x_0$ be an interior point of $C$. Set $y:=x-x_0$.
Then $x+ty=(1+t)x-tx_0 $ cannot be in $C$, otherwise $x = \frac1{1+t}(x+ty) + \frac t{1+t} x_0$ would be an interior point of $C$.

If $x$ is the projection of a point $y\not\in C$, then $x+t(y-x)\not\in C$ for all $t>0$ as well: For $t\in (0,1)$ it follows from the projection property, for $t>1$ it follows with the same argument above.

Still there are situation, where both assumptions are not valid: Take $H=L^2(0,1)$, $C$ the cone of non-negative functions. It has empty interior. The point $x\equiv 1$ is a boundary point of $C$ that is not the projection of an element outside. Still we can construct the desired $y$: $y(x) = -|x|^{1/4}$.

Comment: but what if $C$ does not have any interior point ?

Comment: What goes wrong if you do the same thing but starting with "if $x\in C$ and $x_0\in C$ then $\lambda x+(1-\lambda)x_0\in C$", so as to cover the case where $C$ has no interior?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich $x+ty$ might be still in $C$ (think of a line in 2d)

Comment: @elliptic I have no proof. I feel that the claim should be true, but would not be surprised if somebody comes up with some counterexample.

Comment: Oops. never mind then...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a somewhat opportunistic answer since it is not much more than putting together the ideas of @daw and @gerw,  but I
think it is still justified because it is a self contained proof.

Without loss of generality suppose that the boundary point $x$ referred to in the statement is the orgin.  As observed by @gerw,  assuming by
contradiction that the result is false,  for every $y$ in $H$,  there exists $t>0$ such
that $ty\in  C$.  This is equivalent to the fact that
$$
  H = \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb N} nC,
  $$
so Baire's Theorem implies that $C$ has a nonempty interior which is what one needs to make  @daw's proof work.